# Magento 2 : Add gift message block to billing step in onepage checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am trying to add gift option section on checkout page.

I called gift option by following code. in checkout_index_index.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                    <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

And it display in last.
But I want this section in payment methods brfore payment selection like this.
[image]

How can I achieve this.

Comment: is that your full checkout_index_index?

Comment: Yes i override in my custom theme and contain only this code

Answer (score 2):

I hope you could archive your challenge by this time. For those that might need a clue about this, here we go.

In order to do any change in the checkout steps, you have to follow the instructions described [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html).
After deciding where you wanna include your new component, we can start changing the `checkout_index_index.xml`

In my case, I would like to show the form to add the gift message right after the payment methods, so I will make my component be a child of `afterMethods` that we can find inside the `payment` section, check it out how it looks like down below:

```
     <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                                                    <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

After that, you have to make sure to include the block `Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions` as well, this is because the gift message component will require some information that comes from this function `$block->getGiftOptionsConfigJson()`

So, let's include our block:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

The final file will have this content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                                                    <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

After that, you wanna change the `cart/gift_options.phtml` just a little bit to not load the stack of components twice when you are in the checkout page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div id="gift-options-cart" data-bind="scope:'giftOptionsCart'">
    <!-- Make sure we try to load the knockout stack of components only if we are in the cart page. -->
    <? if( $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName() === 'checkout_cart_index'): ?>
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "#gift-options-cart": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
                }
            }
        </script>
    <? endif ?>
    <script>
        window.giftOptionsConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGiftOptionsConfigJson() ?>;
    </script>
</div>
```

Well, that's all :)

Comment: I upvoted this, because it worked. Didn't place the gift options where the original poster requested, though. And unfortunately, gift options on the checkout page don't work very well because when you click update to save your gift message, it refreshes the page and you lose any information you may have entered in payment methods. I really wish Magento had built better gift options into the base installation.